Neighborhoods in inductive topology
I have a question about the following post in MathStack Exchange (here or read below).

Let $\{X_i\}$ a family of topologcial vector space(equipped with topology $\mathcal{T_i}$).
Let $X = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty X_i$ equipped with inductive topology
w.r.t $\{(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i,I_i)\}$ (the finest topology which makes
$I_i:X_i \to X$ continuous where $I_i$ is the identity map into).
Prove if for each $i$ we have $V\bigcap X_i$ is neighborhood near 0 in
topological vector space $X_i$,then $V$ is a neighborhood near 0 in topological space $X$

I know that this condition is true for open neighborhoods, but is it true for every neighborhood? The answer in that post just proves it for open neighborhoods.

$X$ is not a topological vector space, as it is defined, so what is $0$ meant to be in $X?$

A neighborhood of a point always contains an open neighborhood of the same point, so the proof with open neighborhoods does not restrict generality.
